# Ruby - Singleton module with each. Returning a value gives an Enumerator. How can I get the value instead?

Tags: ruby

Example code:

```
module Creatures
  class << self
    def to_h
      {
          squirtle: {full_name: 'Squirtle T. Turtle'},
          pikachu: {full_name: 'Pikachu B. Pikachu'}
      }
    end
    def keys
      to_h.keys
    end
    def collect
      to_h.keys.collect
    end
    def each
      to_h.keys.each
    end
  end
end

module CompanionHelper
  def get_companion_creature_experience(companion_data)
    Creatures.each do |creature|
      return companion_data[creature]["#{creature}_experience".to_sym] if companion_data.has_key?(creature)
    end
  end
end

include CompanionHelper
companion_data = {squirtle: {squirtle_experience: 8000}}

get_companion_creature_experience(companion_data)
```

Forgive me if the example is contrived. The original code is from the insurance world but I can't copy and paste it :)

The crux of the problem is I want to use `Creatures.each` in another module, pass it a block, and have it work just like `Creatures.keys.each` would work (i.e. w/ the given example companion data I get 8000 for `get_companion_creature_experience(companion_data)`.

Currently I get `Enumerator` instead.

Comment: You should consider just implementing `each` and then including the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) module, which will give you `collect`, `select`, and all of the other Enumerable methods for free.

Comment: I added `include Enumerable` inside the `class << self` block and it seems to be working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `to_h.keys.each` returns `Enumerator` which does not expect any arguments. Pass a block inside `each` since you want to use it:

```
def each &block
  to_h.keys.each &block
end
```

Or you can yield it:

```
def each
  to_h.keys.each do |k|
    yield k
  end
end
```

Comment: That's not correct. `return` raises a LocalJumpError when used outside a method definition.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan and @Ilya. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and the `return` works fine. It was from another coder with a different style, though, and I do prefer to remove it if I can. Looking into what exactly happens if I do... Luckily I tried it with the Pokemon example before putting it in my code at work. It does give a different result....([:squirtle,:pikachu] instead of 8000)

Comment: @Jordan, yes, my bad